# React HTML input maxLength does not show error or do form validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My input is in a form but does no validation for maxLength.

```
<input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="company"
              onBlur={event => setCompany(event.currentTarget.value)}
              maxLength={100}
            />
```

I have made sure to use `maxLength` not `maxLength`, `type="text"` not ex. `type="number"` and `maxLength={100}` not `maxLength="100"` as I am using typescript (.tsx)

I am expecting the form to prevent submission or to highlight the invalid data when the user highlights any other control.

Comment: I'd look at the rendered, final HTML in the DOM.  Otherwise, you can create a [mre] using a [Stack Snippet with JSX support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552)

Comment: Note that, in your "I have made sure to use `maxLength` not `maxLength`, ...", the two terms are identical, so I assume the second one was meant to be something different.

Answer (score 3):

`MaxLength` has nothing to do with "preventing submission" or "highlight the invalid data".

Setting the `MaxLength` just prevents the user from entering characters beyond that length. For example if you set it to 3 and the user holds down 'a', it will go up to 'aaa' and nothing beyond it.

The validation will need to be handled programmatically by reading the [tooLong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState/tooLong) property.